# Why does this stack array result in getline creating a segfault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, getline, stdio, stack-memory

This code works if you remove the array, but I don't know why, and it always segfaults before the printing during the getline function. Why does it do this, and how do I fix it? My actual code looks a little different, but this is the smallest implementation of the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int count = 2;
    int array[count];
    char *text;
    size_t text_size;
    printf("Please enter test text: ");
    getline(&text, &text_size, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

Comment: You haven’t allocated any memory for text

Comment: @DanielA.White doesn't getline allocate its own memory?

Comment: `char *text = NULL;` because `"If *lineptr is set to NULL before the call, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer should be reed by the user program even if getline() failed."` [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: @RetiredNinja put that in an answer and I'll confirm it